# Support for Fonts in Zebra Android SDK

Tags: java, android, zebra-printers

I am printing a receipt using Zebra printer ( Android SDK).
I have checked the documentation of the SDk but could not find any utility class that can help in setting of font size/name/height.

Currently i am hard-coding the parameters and creating a `.lbl` file but i think that is not a good approach.

So, is their any utility class that would generate the script for `.lbl` file depending on set of parameters i provided to it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Zebra SDK does not provide extensive label design support.  It is designed to help with discovery, communication, configuration, and printing to Zebra printers.  To my knowledge there is no real element of the SDK that will help you change font sizes dynamically.

Your approach is correct: defined a .LBL template file, and populate the data at print-time. Often, an end-user wil want to use a nearly identical label (in terms of font size, graphics, positioning) and will simply change the printed data.  Dynamically changing those elements (font size, for example) doesn't seem to be a common need.  That is just my impression.